# Matlab: How to read/write an existing (1*2) struct?

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I have a (1*2 struct). How can i search for a field name? For example i want to select the field name "loadPc" to get the value in the second row. Or should i do it with a loop? What is better?

Is it also possible to override (replace) some values with new values? Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYQIs.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [fieldnames](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) function to get the names of the fields and then extract the data.

When you extract the data, you can include the right part of the instruction within `[]`: this allows storing the data in an array

As an alternative, you can directly specify the name of the field

A possible approach could be:

```
% Define the struct
s(1).field_a=1
s(1).field_b=2
s(1).field_c=3
s(2).field_a=10
s(2).field_b=20
s(2).field_c=30
% Get the field names
str_fields=fieldnames(s)
% Extract the data form the fields
%
% First method
%
% Data from field "field_a"
the_data_1=filed_a_data=[s(:).(str_fields{1})]
% Data from field "field_a"
%
% Second method
%
the_data_2=filed_a_data=[s(:).field_c]
```

Notice in the statement:

```
the_data_1=filed_a_data=[s(:).(str_fields{1})]
```

`s(:)` allows accessing to all the element of the structure array

In the code:

- define an example (1 x 2) struct
- with first method: select the name of the field from the cellarray `str_field` and store the data in the array `the_data_1`
- with the second method: write directly the name of the field and store the data in the array `the_data_2`

Output:

```
the_data_1 =

    1   10

the_data_2 =

    3   30
```